# Python 3.5 and Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Good day,

I am have installed Python 3.5 with all the extra libs required to make Tensorflow work in Windows 10. The IDE I'm using is PyCharm community edition and Python seems to be running fine.

However, I'm getting the following error from Python:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

My code is taken from the Tensorflow Examples page:
[Tensorflow Page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/monitors/)
Which was giving depreciated problems in the first case. So I have gone ahead and started fixing the problems but I am starting to get a little frustrated banging my head against a wall.

Here is my code so far:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

print("=================================Begin Import=================================")

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

print("=================================End Import=================================")

print("=================================Begin Dataset=================================")

# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)

COLUMNS = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
FEATURES = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
LABEL = "5"

training_set1 = pd.read_csv("iris_training.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
test_set1 = pd.read_csv("iris_test.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)

print("=================================End Dataset=================================")

print("=================================Define Features=================================")

''' feature_cols = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k)
                  for k in FEATURES] '''

# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k) for k in FEATURES]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=3,
                                            model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")

print("=================================End Define Features=================================")


def input_fn(data_set):
    fc = tf.constant(data_set[0].values)
    labels = tf.constant(data_set[1].values)
    return fc, labels

print("=================================Fit Model=================================")

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(input_fn(training_set), steps=2000)

print("=================================End Fit Model=================================")

print("=================================Eval Accuracy=================================")

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn(test_set), steps=1)["accuracy"]
print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))

print("=================================End Eval Accuracy=================================")

print("=================================Test New Data=================================")

# Classify two new flower samples.
new_samples = np.array(
    [[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5], [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7], [5.5, 3.9, 5.1, 1.2]], dtype=float)
y = list(classifier.predict(new_samples, as_iterable=True))
print('Predictions: {}'.format(str(y)))
print("=================================End Test New Data=================================")
```

======= TRACE/ERROR LOG ======

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Iris Classification/Main.py"
=================================Begin Import=================================
=================================End Import=================================
=================================Begin Dataset=================================
=================================End Dataset=================================
=================================Define Features=================================
=================================End Define Features=================================
=================================Fit Model=================================
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_evaluation_master': '', '_master': '', '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x000001CDDFC2D0B8>, 'tf_random_seed': None, 'save_summary_steps': 100, 'keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_task_type': None, 'save_checkpoints_steps': None, 'keep_checkpoint_max': 5, 'save_checkpoints_secs': 600, 'tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1
}
, '_environment': 'local', '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_task_id': 0, '_is_chief': True}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Iris Classification/Main.py", line 65, in <module>
    classifier.fit(input_fn(training_set), steps=2000)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Iris Classification/Main.py", line 58, in input_fn
    fc = tf.constant(data_set[0].values)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error trace?

Comment: You shouldn't need values here for `tf.constant`, just pass it `data_set[0/1]`.

Comment: Added the log, I have tried it by just passing data_set[0] - it gives me:     self._x = check_array(x, dtype=x.dtype)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace for the constant case?